# Prisma migration to MySQL on localhost Fails

Tags: prisma

I am new to Prisma & MySQL. I am trying to migrate some sample tables to MySQL. Please, I need your help...

## File - schema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

...

## File - .env

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://admin:admin@localhost:3306/nss
```

...

## MySQL Shell

```
Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select user();
+-----------------+
| user()          |
+-----------------+
| admin@localhost |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.25 sec)

mysql>
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-graphql",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/server.js"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "all"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "3.6.3",
    "graphql": "15.8.0",
    "graphql-scalars": "1.14.1",
    "nexus": "1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^3.12.0",
    "nodemon": "2.0.15",
    "prisma": "^3.12.0"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "node prisma/seed.js"
  }
}
```

In VS-Code Terminal, I issued the command

npx prisma migrate dev

Got the message: Error: Migration engine error:

Comment: Could you please add the description of Migration error?

Comment: Thanks so much @NurulSundarani for your response.

Comment: The bit of error I got is what I just wrote... Error: Migration engine error:      PLease, if you know what I need to do in order to get a more detailed error, you could just let me know. Once again, my sincere appreciation for your response.

Comment: @NurulSundarani  

mysql> show databases
    -> ;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| nss                |
| performance_schema |
| sakila             |
| sys                |
| test               |
| world              |
+--------------------+
8 rows in set